# Changing the LegendText when using Chart.DataBindCrossTable

Tags: c#, mschart

I'm trying to change the legend text in my column chart by using DataBindCrossTable() passing the LegendText as parameter on otherFields.

For example, my data is as follows:

MyData {
  RunTime : DateTime
  Location : String
  Projects : int
}

Then I'm calling

```
chart.DataBindCrossTable(data, "RunTime", "Location", "Projects", "LegendText=RunTime{MM/dd/yyyy}");
```

The resulting chart is ok, except the legend that is showing something like:

> RunTime - 2013-01-01 12:00 AM

I want the legend to show just:

> 2013-01-01

Looks like setting the LegendText does nothing.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could you please try Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(mylist, "RunTime", "Location", "Projects", "Label=RunTime");

Comment: Label just puts a label in the charting area. I want the Legend, not the labels.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution for this. 
When using the DataBindCrossTable, the otherFields parameter does not apply to the Series object. By setting it, the result is applied to each DataPoint in the Series.

```
chart.DataBindCrossTable(data, "RunTime", "Location", "Projects", "LegendText=RunTime{MM/dd/yyyy}");
```

When calling the method above, the points in the Series will have its LegendText property correctly set. What I have done was to set my Series Name with the first point's LegendText, like this:

```
foreach (Series s in chart.Series)
        {
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
            s.Name = s.Points.First().LegendText;
            chart.Legends.Add(GetLegend(s.Name));
        }
```

Then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I only found a dirty way,use the event oncustomizelegend="Chart1_CustomizeLegend" of the chart control

```
    protected void Chart1_CustomizeLegend(object sender, System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LegendItems.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.LegendItems.Count; i++)
            {
                if (e.LegendItems[0].Cells.Count > 1)
                {
                    e.LegendItems[i].Cells[1].Text = e.LegendItems[i].Cells[1].Text.Replace("RunTime - ", "").Replace(" 12:00 AM", "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ugh... really dirty. Actually I have found the answer. It lies on the DataPoints.